# Inserting HTML content at cursor position in content editable div giving error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a project of Angular where I need to insert some HTML dynamically at the cursor position inside a contenteditable div. I am using the following code to achieve this:

Here is the stackblitz demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world-uax5rz

```
 addVariables(event, variable) {
  const editableDiv = document.querySelector('.note-editable');
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  const startPos = range.startOffset;

  let htmlToInsert = '';
  if (variable.variable == 'BUSINESS_LOGO') {
    htmlToInsert = " <img src='${" +
      variable.variable +
      "}'   width='250' height='120'  style='line-height: 100%; outline-color: initial; outline-style: none; outline-width: initial; text-decoration-line: none; text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; box-sizing: border-box; width: 250px; height: 120px;' >";
  } else {
    htmlToInsert = ' ${' + variable.variable.replace(/ /g, '_') + '}';
  }

  range.deleteContents();
  const newElem = document.createElement("span");
  newElem.innerHTML = htmlToInsert;
  range.insertNode(newElem);

  // Set the cursor position to the end of the inserted HTML
  range.setStartAfter(newElem);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  editableDiv.focus();

  const updatedHtml = editableDiv.innerHTML;
  editableDiv.focus();

  // set cursor position at the end of the inserted text
  const cursorPosition = startPos + htmlToInsert.length;
  const newRange = document.createRange();
  newRange.setStart(editableDiv.childNodes[0], cursorPosition);
  newRange.setEnd(editableDiv.childNodes[0], cursorPosition);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(newRange);
}

// patchValue method is not defined in this code snippet, but assuming it's defined elsewhere in your codebase
this.emailForm.patchValue({ body: updatedHtml });
```

But I am getting error saying

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 27.
```